# connection was closed in ignite map reduce tasks

Tags: mapreduce, ignite, in-memory

**Environment**:

ignite server:

centos6.5 with kernel 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64

ignite version 1.9

hadoop version 2.6.2

3 server nodes with each having '-Xms16g -Xmx16g -server -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m' set when started

I run a map reduce test job with ignite map reduce. The job is simply getting the average number for each people. The data is like:

Jack 0.35

Tom 0.78

Lily 0.92

Jack 0.28

Tom 0.18

...

At first, I generated a data set of 100M lines. It's about 2.53GB. The job finished correctly in about 30s. Then I generated a data set of 1 Billion lines, about 25.3GB. The job always failed with exceptions. I tried several times but the same result.

The ignite server node threw exception below:

```
[15:06:56,804][ERROR][sys-#2740%null%][GridTcpRestProtocol] Failed to process client request [ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=ByteBufferNioClientWorker [readBuf=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=549 lim=549 cap=8192], super=AbstractNioClientWorker [selector=sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@1cba0431, idx=3, bytesRcvd=0, bytesSent=0, bytesRcvd0=0, bytesSent0=0, select=true, super=GridWorker [name=grid-nio-worker-tcp-rest-3, gridName=null, finished=false, isCancelled=false, hashCode=906881587, interrupted=false, runner=grid-nio-worker-tcp-rest-3-#50%null%]]], writeBuf=null, readBuf=null, inRecovery=null, outRecovery=null, super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/172.31.68.204:11211, rmtAddr=/172.31.68.202:39473, createTime=1493967985751, closeTime=1493968009502, bytesSent=2715, bytesRcvd=2641, bytesSent0=0, bytesRcvd0=0, sndSchedTime=1493968016794, lastSndTime=1493967998303, lastRcvTime=1493968009502, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioCodecFilter [parser=GridTcpRestParser [jdkMarshaller=JdkMarshaller [], routerClient=false], directMode=false]], accepted=true]], msg=GridClientTaskRequest [taskName=o.a.i.i.processors.hadoop.proto.HadoopProtocolJobStatusTask, arg=HadoopProtocolTaskArguments []]]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to send message (connection was closed): GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=ByteBufferNioClientWorker [readBuf=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=549 lim=549 cap=8192], super=AbstractNioClientWorker [selector=sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@1cba0431, idx=3, bytesRcvd=0, bytesSent=0, bytesRcvd0=0, bytesSent0=0, select=true, super=GridWorker [name=grid-nio-worker-tcp-rest-3, gridName=null, finished=false, isCancelled=false, hashCode=906881587, interrupted=false, runner=grid-nio-worker-tcp-rest-3-#50%null%]]], writeBuf=null, readBuf=null, inRecovery=null, outRecovery=null, super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/172.31.68.204:11211, rmtAddr=/172.31.68.202:39473, createTime=1493967985751, closeTime=1493968009502, bytesSent=2715, bytesRcvd=2641, bytesSent0=0, bytesRcvd0=0, sndSchedTime=1493968016794, lastSndTime=1493967998303, lastRcvTime=1493968009502, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioCodecFilter [parser=GridTcpRestParser [jdkMarshaller=JdkMarshaller [], routerClient=false], directMode=false]], accepted=true]]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.cast(IgniteUtils.java:7239)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get0(GridFutureAdapter.java:170)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get(GridFutureAdapter.java:119)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.protocols.tcp.GridTcpRestNioListener$1$1.apply(GridTcpRestNioListener.java:264)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.protocols.tcp.GridTcpRestNioListener$1$1.apply(GridTcpRestNioListener.java:261)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.notifyListener(GridFutureAdapter.java:271)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.listen(GridFutureAdapter.java:228)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.protocols.tcp.GridTcpRestNioListener$1.apply(GridTcpRestNioListener.java:261)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.protocols.tcp.GridTcpRestNioListener$1.apply(GridTcpRestNioListener.java:229)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.notifyListener(GridFutureAdapter.java:271)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.notifyListeners(GridFutureAdapter.java:259)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.onDone(GridFutureAdapter.java:389)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.onDone(GridFutureAdapter.java:355)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.onDone(GridFutureAdapter.java:332)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.GridRestProcessor$2$1.apply(GridRestProcessor.java:158)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.GridRestProcessor$2$1.apply(GridRestProcessor.java:155)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.notifyListener(GridFutureAdapter.java:271)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.notifyListeners(GridFutureAdapter.java:259)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.onDone(GridFutureAdapter.java:389)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.onDone(GridFutureAdapter.java:355)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.onDone(GridFutureAdapter.java:332)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureChainListener.applyCallback(GridFutureChainListener.java:78)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureChainListener.apply(GridFutureChainListener.java:70)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureChainListener.apply(GridFutureChainListener.java:30)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.notifyListener(GridFutureAdapter.java:271)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.notifyListeners(GridFutureAdapter.java:259)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.onDone(GridFutureAdapter.java:389)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.onDone(GridFutureAdapter.java:355)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.onDone(GridFutureAdapter.java:332)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.handlers.task.GridTaskCommandHandler$2.apply(GridTaskCommandHandler.java:294)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.handlers.task.GridTaskCommandHandler$2.apply(GridTaskCommandHandler.java:257)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.notifyListener(GridFutureAdapter.java:271)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.notifyListeners(GridFutureAdapter.java:259)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.onDone(GridFutureAdapter.java:389)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.onDone(GridFutureAdapter.java:355)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.finishTask(GridTaskWorker.java:1579)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.finishTask(GridTaskWorker.java:1547)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.reduce(GridTaskWorker.java:1157)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.onResponse(GridTaskWorker.java:942)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor.processJobExecuteResponse(GridTaskProcessor.java:996)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor$JobMessageListener.onMessage(GridTaskProcessor.java:1221)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1222)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:850)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$2100(GridIoManager.java:108)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$7.run(GridIoManager.java:790)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to send message (connection was closed): GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=ByteBufferNioClientWorker [readBuf=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=549 lim=549 cap=8192], super=AbstractNioClientWorker [selector=sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@1cba0431, idx=3, bytesRcvd=0, bytesSent=0, bytesRcvd0=0, bytesSent0=0, select=true, super=GridWorker [name=grid-nio-worker-tcp-rest-3, gridName=null, finished=false, isCancelled=false, hashCode=906881587, interrupted=false, runner=grid-nio-worker-tcp-rest-3-#50%null%]]], writeBuf=null, readBuf=null, inRecovery=null, outRecovery=null, super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/172.31.68.204:11211, rmtAddr=/172.31.68.202:39473, createTime=1493967985751, closeTime=1493968009502, bytesSent=2715, bytesRcvd=2641, bytesSent0=0, bytesRcvd0=0, sndSchedTime=1493968016794, lastSndTime=1493967998303, lastRcvTime=1493968009502, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioCodecFilter [parser=GridTcpRestParser [jdkMarshaller=JdkMarshaller [], routerClient=false], directMode=false]], accepted=true]]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer.send0(GridNioServer.java:554)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer.send(GridNioServer.java:494)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$HeadFilter.onSessionWrite(GridNioServer.java:3036)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterAdapter.proceedSessionWrite(GridNioFilterAdapter.java:118)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioCodecFilter.onSessionWrite(GridNioCodecFilter.java:94)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterAdapter.proceedSessionWrite(GridNioFilterAdapter.java:118)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterChain$TailFilter.onSessionWrite(GridNioFilterChain.java:264)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterChain.onSessionWrite(GridNioFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioSessionImpl.send(GridNioSessionImpl.java:108)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.protocols.tcp.GridTcpRestNioListener$1.apply(GridTcpRestNioListener.java:258)
    ... 40 more
```

The job client threw exception below:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to get job status: job_1fbf9083-9a44-4be9-9199-695a97652dc2_0002
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.hadoop.impl.proto.HadoopClientProtocol.getJobStatus(HadoopClientProtocol.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$1.run(Job.java:326)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$1.run(Job.java:323)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1656)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.updateStatus(Job.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.isComplete(Job.java:611)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.monitorAndPrintJob(Job.java:1357)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1318)
    at com.tscloud.sdk.test.ignite.MRTest.run(MRTest.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at com.tscloud.sdk.test.ignite.MRTest.main(MRTest.java:53)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.internal.client.impl.connection.GridClientConnectionResetException: Failed to perform request (connection failed): /172.31.68.204:11211
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.impl.connection.GridClientConnection.getCloseReasonAsException(GridClientConnection.java:491)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.impl.connection.GridClientNioTcpConnection.close(GridClientNioTcpConnection.java:339)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.impl.connection.GridClientNioTcpConnection.close(GridClientNioTcpConnection.java:299)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.impl.connection.GridClientConnectionManagerAdapter$NioListener.onDisconnected(GridClientConnectionManagerAdapter.java:630)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterChain$TailFilter.onSessionClosed(GridNioFilterChain.java:253)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterAdapter.proceedSessionClosed(GridNioFilterAdapter.java:93)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioCodecFilter.onSessionClosed(GridNioCodecFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterAdapter.proceedSessionClosed(GridNioFilterAdapter.java:93)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$HeadFilter.onSessionClosed(GridNioServer.java:3005)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterChain.onSessionClosed(GridNioFilterChain.java:147)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.close(GridNioServer.java:2306)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$ByteBufferNioClientWorker.processRead(GridNioServer.java:929)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.processSelectedKeysOptimized(GridNioServer.java:2026)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.bodyInternal(GridNioServer.java:1863)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.body(GridNioServer.java:1568)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The job configuration is below:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.set(MRConfig.FRAMEWORK_NAME, IgniteHadoopClientProtocolProvider.FRAMEWORK_NAME);
configuration.set(MRConfig.MASTER_ADDRESS, "172.31.68.202:11211");
configuration.set("fs.igfs.impl", "org.apache.ignite.hadoop.fs.v1.IgniteHadoopFileSystem");
configuration.set("fs.default.name", "igfs://igfs@172.31.68.202/");
```

I checked nodes status after the job failed using ignitevisorcmd.sh. All server nodes were OK, but there were sometime one of the node server was down. I did not know why it behaved like this.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit(2017-05-16):
I changed the hadoop core-site.xml and add hadoop.tmp.dir property as below

```
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/data/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.2/tmp</value>
  </property>
```

Then I reformatted hdfs and uploaded the 25.3GB data file. I run the test successfully. It turns out my hdfs has something wrong. Reformatting namenode solves the problem.

Before above steps, I tried checking the jvm heap usage by VisualVM.

[One of the server node visualvm monitor snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTalN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your node was down temporarily, then it is reasonable that a job would fail-over to another node or fail altogether if there are no other nodes. I would check that your network was not reset or down. Also, you should check for the presence of any software firewalls between your nodes (it is best to disable operating system firewalls).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The network is ok. It did not happen every time that one of the nodes was down. And for a smaller data set, the job always finished correctly.

Comment: Are you sure you are not running out of memory?

Comment: No. The data file is about 25.3GB, and total server nodes jvm heap is 48GB, each 16GB.

Comment: Allen, there are a lot more factors. Please use VisualVM or other tool to check if you have memory issues. You can also refer to this page to estimate how much memory you need to store your data in Ignite: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/capacity-planning

Comment: @ValentinKulichenko I did not see other exceptions in the log. I will use VisualVM to check again.

BTW, does ignite requires each node's heap size larger than the data file size?

Comment: Ignite doesn't store data in files, it's a key-value storage. Thus correlation between the size of your file and memory required for Ignite is not that simple. Please refer to the guide I provided in previous message.